# JMS request/response pattern in transactional environment

Tags: transactions, glassfish, ejb, jms, java-ee-7

I have an EJB module that has to synchronously exchange messages with a MDB in another module via TemporaryQueue. The EJB container (in my case it's Glassfish 4.0) assumes transactional environment, do I have to use BEAN-managed transaction and denote start and end of transactions using UserTransaction object.

The outline of my code is like this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class CommunicationJMSUtils {
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction ut;
    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/DestinationQueue")
    private Queue destination;
    private static final long JMS_COMMUNICATION_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    public Map<String, String> getClientordersData(String id) throws JMSException {

    try {
            MapMessage mm = context.createMapMessage();
            ut.begin();
            TemporaryQueue replyQueue = context.createTemporaryQueue();

            mm.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);

            mm.setStringProperty(<...>);
            <...>   
            mm.setString(<...>);
            <...>

            context.createProducer().send(destination, mm);
            ut.commit();

            ut.begin();
            ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage) context.createConsumer(replyQueue).receive(JMS_COMMUNICATION_TIMEOUT);
            ut.commit();

            if (om != null) {
                return om.getBody(Map.class);
            } else {
                throw new JMSException("Failed to receive reply within " + JMS_COMMUNICATION_TIMEOUT);
            }
        } catch (NotSupportedException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException | SecurityException | IllegalStateException | SystemException ex) {
        <...>
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is that from time to time this code (receive part) fails with exception

```
    MQJMSRA_DS4001: _checkDestination:Temporary Destination not owned by  parent connectionId=1760697170479431168
```

although evidently TemporaryQueue is created with same JMSContext.

And the second problem is the "fragility" of this code. If I put context.createMapMessage() inside the first transaction or move TemporaryQueue creation out of the first transaction this snippet will definately fail.

Unfortunately, JMS tutorials/documentation do not really cover that particular use-case. What is the correct way to implement the JMS request/response pattern with JMS 2.0 in Java EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Synchronous behaviour and (asynchronous) messaging using JMS conflict somehow, as messaging is asynchronous by nature. Instead of using JMS, just call the method, for example on a local or remote EJB: A stateless session bean and an MDB can call the same functionality (service class), but this way they provide two different types of interfaces (sync & async).
- You are even creating a temporary queue for calling a method, this does add complexity (and this is causing trouble).
- The `UserTransaction` should span all operations. There should be only one `begin`, and `commit` (and `rollback`). I cannot see a real transaction boundary, resources from the first TX are used in the 2nd TX (`replyQueue`). I would expect that the temporary queue was deleted during the first `commit`.
- Possibly related: An EJB with `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` acts as a "transaction barrier". It will possibly suspend a current transaction: [Why do EJB beans with bean-managed transactions act as a “transacation barrier”? here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17898154/2390083)

So instead of fixing the transaction handling I suggest adding a stateless session bean which offers the same functionality, and call this one (synchronously). In that case I do not see a reason why this should not work with container managed transactions, and thus it will be really transactional across bean boundaries.

Comment: Asynchronous messaging was chosen to avoid having specific interfaces between modules (to be able to substitude one for another). I see know that Remote interfaces may be more or less used in the same way.
The resource sharing between transaction is a real issue here (and the reason of this question in general). In the literature you can sometimes find synchronous exchange pattern with JMS but without clear implementation example.
Thank you for your reply, I think I have to reconsider architecture design.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to use bean-managed transactions. Unless you need to have fine-grained control over many different transactions within a business method, it makes more sense to let the container manage the transactions.

Comment: @IanEvans It seems that your comment is for the OP. Anyway my answer deals with a general aspect of BMT only, and the suggestion/conclusion is another design (and CMT should be fine in that case).

Comment: @Beryllium: yes, sorry. I meant that for the OP. And I agree with your answer re: BMT.

Comment: @IanEvans I would be happy to leave transaction processing to container but unfortunately I have to use bean-managed transactions because it is impossible to send a request and get a reply within one transaction (in this case it's a method call). There are at least two options what to do with it:
1. Use Bean-managed transactions to separate sending and receiving.
2. Use two session beans, one to send a request and another to receive a reply.
As a reference I have used the following [article].(http://frankkieviet.blogspot.fr/2006/08/jms-requestreply-from-ejb.html).

Comment: @user836961: In that case, use two transactions. `@Resource private UserTransaction ut1` and `@Resource private UserTransaction ut2`.

Comment: @IanEvans Thank you for your time! Actually, I have never seen in manuals that `UserTransaction` object cannot be reused. Unfortunately, even with separate transactions I still sometimes  get the original `MQJMSRA_DS4001` exception (`Temporary Destination not owned by  parent connectionId=...`). It seems to me that problem is `TemporaryQueue` that is shared between transactions but unfortunately such scenario isn't really covered in documentation.
All in all, to solve the problem I am going to replace this code section with Remote EJB invocation.